# How to send dictionary as parameter to python function

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

Below code does not work, data is a dictionary & I was wondering how to pass it to function

```
def my_function(x={}):
for i , j in x:
    print (i)
    print (j)

data = {'a':1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}
my_function(**data)
```

Comment: Have you tried simply *passing the dictionary as an argument*? `my_function(data)`

Comment: its not a good practice to have default argument value mutable!

Comment: @AmitKarnik it's not that it's not "good practice", but that it doesn't work as most peoples would expect http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/writing/gotchas/#mutable-default-arguments

Comment: yes, that's what I wanted to say. Anyway, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The below code should work for you:

```
def my_function(x={}):
    for i, j in x.iteritems():
        print (i)
        print (j)

data = {'a':1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}
my_function(data)
```

**Explanation**

- Ensure your indentation is correct.
- To iterate a dictionary, use `dict.iteritems` (in Python 2.x) or `dict.items` (in Python 3).
- If you are iterating the dictionary in this way, there is no reason to use an unpacking `**` operator.
- Understand the pitfalls of using [Mutable Default Arguments](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/writing/gotchas/#mutable-default-arguments).

Comment: Just beware of the mutable default argument gotcha if your real function mutates it's argument (http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/writing/gotchas/#mutable-default-arguments)

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers, good point - in this specific usage not an issue, but I'll add that link.